# JavaEdit search function not locating visible element

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I've got two library functions:

```
Function searchWindow(title)

     Set searchWindow = Window("title:=" + title)

End Function
```

And

```
Function searchField(label)

     Set searchField =  JavaEdit("attached text:=" + label)

End Function
```

Here I'm testing them:

```
Environment.Loadfromfile("C:\UFTConstants\constants.ini")

Set loginFrame = searchWindow(Environment.Value("frameLogin"))

loginFrame.Click

Set userField = searchField("User ID / Ci-Usager")

userField.Set "test"
```

The first function works fine, and it's title property matches that of the application. However, the second will not find the text field, despite properties matching:

[image]

The error:

[image]

I've tried other properties as well, tagname, various class properties, as well as combinations of all three, and none are producing a find.

Any ideas?

## First Update

As per request, full spy screencap:

[image]

The full line generated by the recording tool:

```
JavaWindow("Application Name").JavaDialog("Window Title").JavaEdit("User ID / Ci-Usager").Set "user"
```

However, when I try to re-create this programmatically, I get the same error, only for JavaWindow instead:

"Cannot identify the object [JavaWindow] of (class JavaWindow)..."

Possible Java set-up issue? This would not explain why recording can still locate Java objects, however.

## Second Update

Here are the recognition properties:

[image]

I have ensured that all properties are set, still unable to locate.

## Final Update

Ok, I've reduced the code to absolute barebones. No external constant file, no external library calls. I've copied the full extent of what is recorded in recording mode. I've printed each variable to ensure accuracy. I've included the full object hierarchy:

```
Set objWin = JavaWindow("label:=<redacted>")

objWin.SetTOProperty "to_class", "JavaWindow"

objWin.SetTOProperty "toolkit class", "javax.swing.JFrame"

MsgBox objWin.GetTOProperty("label")
MsgBox objWin.GetTOProperty("to_class")
MsgBox objWin.GetTOProperty("toolkit class")

Set objDialog = objWin.JavaDialog("label:=<redacted>")

objDialog.SetTOProperty "to_class", "JavaDialog"

objDialog.SetTOProperty "toolkit class", "<redacted>.LoginDialog"

MsgBox objDialog.GetTOProperty("label")
MsgBox objDialog.GetTOProperty("to_class")
MsgBox objDialog.GetTOProperty("toolkit class")

Set objEdit = objDialog.JavaEdit("attached text:=User ID / Ci-Usager")

objEdit.SetTOProperty "to_class", "JavaEdit"

objEdit.SetTOProperty "toolkit class", "javax.swing.JTextField"

MsgBox objEdit.GetTOProperty("attached text")
MsgBox objEdit.GetTOProperty("to_class")
MsgBox objEdit.GetTOProperty("toolkit class")

objEdit.Set "test"
```

Note the redacted text is to remove identifying elements from the code. They have been triple-checked on my side and are correct.

This still does not work.

However, recording the same does. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to mention the full hierarchy while working with the Javaedit field. Try re-writing the code for the function `searchField` as :

```
Function searchField(label)
     Dim objFrame
     Set objFrame = searchWindow(Environment.Value("frameLogin"))
     Set searchField =  objFrame.JavaEdit("attached text:=" + label)       'Javaedit should be the child of the login window. You had to mention the full hierarchy here
End Function
```

Comment: I did try this as RFT works in a similar fashion, but UFT still refuses to recognize the field, and due to UFT's almost non-existent error reporting I'm not sure what other options to pursue.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the object spy highlighting the webedit in the OP

Comment: @TheFaster May be there is an extra space or no space somewhere. I know you must have made sure about it but could you please recheck the value contained in the variable-label is exactly same as what is displayed in your screenshot. To achieve that, Open the object spy, click on the value(User ID / Ci-Usager), COPY and PASTE it in your code(do not write on your own-just copy&paste).

Comment: @Kira Good suggestion, but I know enough about my own capacity for error to trust freehand typing over copy-paste. All values in the code are copy-pasted from the Spy values

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar Added a full screencap

Comment: In object identification settings, for an object of class Javaedit, what properties are set inside the mandatory and assistive properties group for identifying that object uniquely? May be you should provide all those property-value pairs in the code.

Comment: Or try adding that object temporarily in your local OR. After adding, see what all property-value pairs have been captured in OR. And use all those values in your code.

Comment: From the image which you have posted, it seems that javaedit is the child of javadialog and not javawindow. May be that is the reason.  Again you could be sure about the hierarchy by temporarily adding the object to OR.

Comment: Agree with @kira, try recording the step you are trying to program by using inline descriptive, that should give you the exact hierarchy that qtp is expecting.

Comment: @Kira Updated per your requests

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar Updated as per Kira's request